# Parsing String with fixed-width fields but different length

Tags: java

I need to parse a long string with this pattern:

```
1)'*'   (text,len:1)
2)accountCount  (number,len:2)
3)accountNumber1    (text,len:20)
4)accountNumber2    (text,len:20)
5)accountNumber3    (text,len:20)
6)accountNumber4    (text,len:20)
...
?)accountNumber'$accountCount'  (text,len:20)
?)'^'   (text,len:1)
```

As you can see, the accountNumber field will be repeated in 'accountCount' times.

What is the best way to declare a class for my `String` and set the `accountCount,accountNumber1,accountNumber2,accountNumber3,...` properties?

Answer (score 2):

Using guava [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

```
final String in = "* 3      accountNumber1      accountNumber2      accountNumber3^";
final Iterable<String> accounts = Splitter.fixedLength(20).trimResults().split(in.subString(3, in.length - 1);
```

Something like that. You can then "transform" `accounts` into a `List` of `Account` object if needed.